# Error Json : "NSDebugDescription Garbage at end" (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing

**hello,**

Even if I did research, I found nothing who can help me in my situation.

So, I try to parse Json created by a php script on xcode but I have an error which blocks the process.

I'm new so I triedto do the best for the layout of my question...

***My error :***

```
[376:70b] Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Garbage at end.) UserInfo=0x8bc0f70 {NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.
```

***My code :***

```
NSData *jsonSource = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                          [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://codlobbyz.com/app/service.php"]];
    NSError *err;
    id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:
                      jsonSource options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
    NSLog(@"%@", err);
```

***My json :***

```
[{"nom":"Call of duty ghost","date":"22 novembre","image":"appicon.png"},{"nom":"Fifa 14","date":"22 novembre","image":"appicon.png"}]
```

**I hope you will help me, thank you for your answers.**

Comment: If you go on http://jsonlint.com and try with your URL http://codlobbyz.com/app/service.php, and try with your URL, it says that your JSON isn't compliant. Seems that your WS is sending other data (that is garbage).

Comment: hm, so when i visit this URL and paste the json from example the validator says "VALID JSON"...

Comment: @thorb, compare the JSON in the question with the response data from http://codlobbyz.com/app/service.php

Comment: It's because the navigator will "erase/interpret" some HTML or whatever web language and not render (as : show the user) it.

Comment: ok, with curl i saw the problem :-D

Comment: I thought this but I thought It was not a problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The PHP script is returning JSON, but also a snippet of HTML that follows it:

```
[{"nom":"Call of duty ghost","date":"22 novembre","image":"appicon.png"},{"nom":"Fifa 14","date":"22 novembre","image":"appicon.png"}] 
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

You can see this by using curl from the command line:

```
curl http://codlobbyz.com/app/service.php
```

Or by loading it in a browser and viewing the source.

If you have control over the PHP script, remove the analytics code. Otherwise, you could use a regex to remove the non-JSON part of the response before parsing it.

EDIT: To remote the non-JSON with regex, something like this would work:

```
NSString *json = @"[{\"nom\":\"Call of duty ghost\",\"date\":\"22 novembre\",\"image\":\"appicon.png\"},{\"nom\":\"Fifa 14\",\"date\":\"22 novembre\",\"image\":\"appicon.png\"}]\n<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->\n<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php\"></script>\n<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\s+<!--.*$"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators
                                                                         error:nil];
NSTextCheckingResult *result = [regex firstMatchInString:json
                                                 options:0
                                                   range:NSMakeRange(0, json.length)];
if(result) {
    NSRange range = [result rangeAtIndex:0];
    json = [json stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"json: %@", json);
}
```

Comment: In 8 hours i will post the final code ! (i can't now because i'm new user :) )

Answer (score 0):

If you look on raw Data you will find '0' inside to remove them I used following for loop

```
NSData *objectData = [jsonStr  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSError *error;
            id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
            if (json == nil) {
                int index = 0;
                const char *bytes = [data bytes];
                for (int i = (int)data.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
                    unsigned char ch = (unsigned char)bytes[i];
                    NSLog(@"%02hhx", ch);
                    if (ch != 0) {
                        index = i+1;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                NSRange dataRange = NSMakeRange(0, index);
                json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[objectData subdataWithRange:dataRange] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
            }
```

This will cut off all '00' bytes from end of your data.